# R: Creating a moving difference variable

Tags: r

I'm attempting to create a new row that is a moving differences between two values in panel data.

My data looks like this:

```
party_id year country position vote
    101 1984      be     2.75   2.3
    101 1988      be     2.75   0.8
    101 1992      be     3.33   0.1
    101 1996      be     3.67   0.1
    102 1984      be     5.80   12.6
    102 1988      be     5.80   15.7
```

I want a row which shows the difference in the vote share for two different years: e.g. 1988 and 1984. So that it shows changes in vote share.

So my data would look like:

```
party_id year country position vote vote_difference
    101 1984      be     2.75   2.3    NA
    101 1988      be     2.75   0.8   -1.5
    101 1992      be     3.33   0.1   -0.7
    101 1996      be     3.67   0.1    0.0
    102 1984      be     5.80   12.6   NA
    102 1988      be     5.80   15.7   3.1
```

Any ideas?

Thanks for the help

Comment: you're not specific enough. your output suggests you want the vote difference _within party_; is it also within country?

Comment: Sorry, vote difference within party

Comment: Have you tried using `diff()` in conjunction with `aggregate()` or `ddply()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R solution that applies the indicated function to `vote` grouped by `party_id`:

```
transform(DF, diff = ave(vote, party_id, FUN = function(x) c(NA, diff(x))))
```

giving:

```
  party_id year country position vote diff
1      101 1984      be     2.75  2.3   NA
2      101 1988      be     2.75  0.8 -1.5
3      101 1992      be     3.33  0.1 -0.7
4      101 1996      be     3.67  0.1  0.0
5      102 1984      be     5.80 12.6   NA
6      102 1988      be     5.80 15.7  3.1
```

**Note:** The input `DF` in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "party_id year country position vote
    101 1984      be     2.75   2.3
    101 1988      be     2.75   0.8
    101 1992      be     3.33   0.1
    101 1996      be     3.67   0.1
    102 1984      be     5.80   12.6
    102 1988      be     5.80   15.7 "
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table); setDT(data)

data[ , vote_difference := diff(vote), by = party_id]
```